# Simple anti robot filter for my form

Tags: php

I made this little [CAPTCHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) type thing for an email form, but for some reason, even when I put in the right answer (4 in this case) I get the else statement. Why?

Here's the code:

#### HTML

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-3">
<label>What is the sum of 2 and 2?</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="robo_q" id="robo_q">
</div>
```

#### PHP

```
<?php
    if ($_POST['$robo_q'] == 4) {

        $nambre = $_POST['name'];
        $number = $_POST['number'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $user_message = $_POST['message'];
        $message = "<h3>From:&nbsp;".$nambre."</h1>";
        $message .= "<h3>Phone:&nbsp;".$number."</h3><br/>";
        $message .=$user_message;

        $headers = "From: " . strip_tags($_POST['email']) . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['email']) . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
        mail ('email@email.com', 'Someone is contacting you from you website', $message, $headers );
        header("location: success.html");
    }
    else {

      header("location: recaptcha.html");
    }
?>
```

Comment: Are you planning to close that input tag?

Comment: Input tags don't need to be closed, unless you just mean the /> at the end. Has no impact on this issue

Comment: The `/>` is only needed for XHTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
if ($_POST['$robo_q'] == 4) {
```

should just be:

```
if ($_POST['robo_q'] == 4) {
```

Note the removal of the `$`. The key in $_POST **MUST** match exactly the `name` you embedded in the HTML form.

Comment: No, the name does not have a $ in it

Comment: @ManofSnow: the actual html is posted above the PHP code. There's a `$` in the PHP, and none in the html...

Comment: Gotta love trolls.. I'm +1 this one over Mike W answer only because this explains to the user what the fix actually was. Ok I'll +1 both!

Comment: @MarcB Sorry, I didn't look at his HTML

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the wrong variable.

Try this:

```
if ($_POST['robo_q'] == 4) {   // No $
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here

```
if ($_POST['$robo_q'] == 4) {
```

`$robo_q` is not a variable, change it to just `robo_q`. Your new code would be

```
<?php

    if ($_POST['robo_q'] == 4) {

        $nambre = $_POST['name'];
        $number = $_POST['number'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $user_message = $_POST['message'];
        $message = "<h3>From:&nbsp;".$nambre."</h1>";
        $message .= "<h3>Phone:&nbsp;".$number."</h3><br/>";
        $message .=$user_message;

        $headers = "From: " . strip_tags($_POST['email']) . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['email']) . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
        mail ('email@email.com', 'Someone is contacting you from you website', $message, $headers);
        header("location: success.html");
    }
    else {

      header("location: recaptcha.html");
    }
?>
```